# Creating Task With a Batch File - run task as soon as possible if missed

Tags: command-line, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

When creating a task with a batch file or command line, how do I specify the following option?

```
Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed
```

I know that this option exists via the GUI, but I need to specify it via command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no command line option for this.  One workaround is to create the tasks with that option, using the GUI, then export it to an XML file.  Then you can run it with

```
schtasks /create /TN "New Task" /xml "C:\TEMP\New Task.xml" /RU DOMAIN\username /RP password
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Good to know its not possible with just commandline either.

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible now after 4 years?

Answer (score 7):

Powershell to rescue, use -StartWhenAvailable

```
Set-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName $TaskName `
    -TaskPath $TaskPath `
    -Trigger $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At "01.01.2018 05:00:00" -DaysOfWeek $day -Weekly -Verbose) `
    -Settings $(New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with VBscript too.
In win 7 there is no Set-ScheduledTask in Powershell.

```vb
Set objTaskService = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
objTaskService.Connect()

Set objRootFolder = objTaskService.GetFolder("\")
Set objTask = objTaskService.NewTask(0)

objTask.RegistrationInfo.Description = "My Scheduled Task"
objTask.Settings.Enabled = True
objTask.Settings.Hidden = False
objTask.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = True 'Run the task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed

Set objTrigger = objTask.Triggers.Create(1)
objTrigger.StartBoundary = "2023-04-08T12:00:00"
objTrigger.Enabled = True
objTrigger.Id = "DailyTrigger"
objTrigger.Repetition.Interval = "PT1M"
objTrigger.Repetition.Duration = "PT1H"

Set objAction = objTask.Actions.Create(0)
objAction.Path = "D:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe"

objRootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition "MyTask", objTask, 6, , , 3
```